# Renaming vs Adding Column to a DataFrame within a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scope

I had have a function which:

1. Defines a list of dictionaries. One item in each dictionary is a dataframe.
2. It then adds a column to dataframe
3. then renames a column in same dataframe
4. And then returns the list from (1)

The function looks like this:

```
def func():
    list1= [
             {"item":1, "df":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"])},
             {"item":2, "df":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"])}
           ]
    for dict1 in list1:
        df = dict1["df"]
        df["col3"] = np.nan # This works as intended
        df = df.rename(columns={"col1":"new_col1"}) # This doesn't work as intended
    
    return list1
```

when I look at the result, the df has col3 but not new_col1:

```
print(func()[0]["df"])

# Output:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
```

I don't understand why that's happening. From what I understand about scope, either both creation & renaming of the new column should go in or neither goes in. Why is one going in and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

In order to persist the change of column name, you need to set `inplace=True`:

```
df.rename(columns={"col1":"new_col1"}, inplace=True)
```

The default setting of inplace=False according to the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Comment: There's no need to reassign the result when using `inplace=True`

Comment: In fact, it's wrong -- it returns `None` when doing inplace replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line (`df = dict1["df"]`), `df` points to the wanted DataFrame, and you can use the variable to work on it.

In the last line (`df = df.rename(columns={"col1":"new_col1"})`) you create a new DataFrame, assign it to `df` and nothing else happens. The variable is local and will be lost.

You must assign back to the dictionary:

```
def func():
    list1= [
             {"item":1, "df":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"])},
             {"item":2, "df":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"])}
           ]
    for dict1 in list1:
        df = dict1["df"]
        df["col3"] = np.nan # This works as intended
        dict1['df'] = df.rename(columns={"col1":"new_col1"})
    
    return list1

print(func())
```

Output:

```
[{'item': 1,
  'df': Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [new_col1, col2, col3]
  Index: []},
 {'item': 2,
  'df': Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [new_col1, col2, col3]
  Index: []}]
```